# Adding, subtracting, dividing and multiplying two numbers. Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to take a simple calculator in Java and convert the code to Kotlin as an example, I've never used Kotlin before and I'm lost. I'm trying to take a number from a editText and convert it to a float to do the actual conversions and then do the operations on these for the result

```
        var value1: Float? = null
        var value2: Float? = null
        var suma: Boolean = false
        var resta: Boolean = false
        var multi: Boolean = false
        var div: Boolean = false

        plus.setOnClickListener {
            if (expression == null) {
                expression.text = ""
            } else {
                value1 = expression.text.toString().toFloat()
                suma = true
                expression.text = ""
            }
        }

        mul.setOnClickListener {
            if (expression == null) {
                expression.text = ""
            } else {
                value1 = expression.text.toString().toFloat()
                multi = true
                expression.text = ""
            }
        }

        minus.setOnClickListener {
            if (expression == null) {
                expression.text = ""
            } else {
                value1 = expression.text.toString().toFloat()
                resta = true
                expression.text = ""
            }
        }

        divide.setOnClickListener {
            if (expression == null) {
                expression.text = ""
            } else {
                value1 = expression.text.toString().toFloat()
                div = true
                expression.text = ""
            }
        }

        dot.setOnClickListener {
            expression.text = expression.text.toString() + "."
        }

        clear.setOnClickListener {
            expression.text = ""
            value1 = null
            value2 = null
        }

        equal.setOnClickListener {
            value2 = expression.text.toString().toFloat()

            if (suma) {
                var s = value1 + value2
                expression.text = s.toString()
            }
            if (resta) {
                var r = value1 - value2
                expression.text = r.toString()
            }
            if (div) {
                var d = value1 / value2
                expression.text = d.toString()
            }
            if (multi) {
                var m = value1 * value2
                expression.text = m.toString()
            }
        }
```

When I try to do the adding, subtracting, multiplying or dividing the code is underlined in red after the operator and the value2 as well, the suggestion is to do this `value1.plus(value2)` but if I do that it also is in red and says `only save or non-null asserted calls are allowed on a nullable reciever of type Float?` If I follow all the suggestions it gives me it still doesn't stop being underlined in red.

This is how I'm starting the values

```
var value1: Float? = null
var value2: Float? = null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't make your values nullable. It's rarely necessary to need nullable primitive properties. The error you're getting is because you're trying to use values that *might* be null.

Instantiate them like this.

```
var value1: Float = 0f
var value2: Float = 0f
```

And in your `clear()` function, set them back to `0f` rather than `null`.

If you really have to keep them null, you could do something like this where you only add them after checking they are both non-null, and then show an error message if either value is null:

```
if (suma) {
    val s = value1?.let { value2?.plus(it) }
    expression.text = s?.toString() ?: "Invalid input value(s)"
}
//...
```

*Edit in response to your comment:*

A typical calculator just resets the operator when you press = before anything else, so I would rewrite the equal button's listener like this (with a when statement for simplicity). I'm removing the `value2` member property because it's unnecessary and using a local property instead.

```
equal.setOnClickListener {
    val value2 = expression.text.toString().toFloatOrNull()
    if (value2 != null) {
        val result = when {
            suma -> value1 + value2
            resta -> value1 - value2
            div -> value1 / value2
            multi -> value1 * value2
            else -> value1 // Shouldn't happen but can default to not changing number
        }
        expression.text = result.toString()
    }

    // reset for next operation
    suma = false
    resta = false
    div = false
    multi = false
}
```

Comment: I used your first suggestion, how can I check if both value1 and value2 are not empty do then do the calculations, right now if I click the equals button and nothing else first the app just closes